# Saving a gml layer does not change coordinates

Tags: qgis, convert, coordinates, gml

I am trying to export a gml layer to geojson with lat/lng as the preferred coordinate system. So what I did was a 'save as' on the layer with selected CRS: 'IGNF: WGS84G'.

Now I was hoping it converted the coordinates of the GML but it did not.

Part of GML data:

```
<gml:PolygonPatch>
    <gml:exterior>
        <gml:LinearRing>
            <gml:posList>264124.695 566223.95</gml:posList>
        </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:exterior>
</gml:PolygonPatch>
```

Part of converted JSON data:

"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 264124.695, 566223.95 ] ] ] ] }

As you can see the coordinates remain the same. I tried other formats in order to test if something is converted but not. I am not an expert on GIS transformations so probably I did something wrong.

Environment:
Windows 2012 Standard running inside VMWare Fusion
QGIS version: 2.0.1 - Dafour 64 Bit

A screenshot of my actions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The GML data you provided is not WGS84, but in a projected CRS using metres as units. It is usually specified inside the gml document with

```
srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/...."
```

`Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer` should be set to the correct CRS. It might be set currently to EPSG:4326 which is obviously wrong. WGS84 data must always be inside +/- 180/90°.

---

**EDIT 1**

Until you have fixed the broken installation, try a custom CRS with

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

for your layer.

And `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs` for the output if that fails too.

---

**EDIT 2**

Testing the data from the download link you gave on 32-bit QGIS Dufour, the gml layer is correctly loaded as EPSG:28992. Saving as Geojson with EPSG:4326 works as expected. The extent of the geojson is `xMin,yMin 3.30794;50.7504 : xMax,yMax 7.2275;53.5764`

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I checked it and it is:

    <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:28992" srsDimension="2">

I saved the project and changed the project settings to WGS84.  Then the coordinate system changes to lat/lng. The visible layer becomes somehow 'invisible' because I guess the layer self remains  in meters. I quickly did a conversion (layer save as) but it remains meters. I will keep on investigating.

Comment: Have you set the **layer** CRS to EPSG:28992 too? Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately this newbie QGIS-gisser cannot find a layer setting having this identity. See my screenshot for CRS-ses on my system when filtering on EP. Luckily my ogr2ogr conversion (see my other comment) seems to work and gives identical coordinates  when using an GML to KML online converter. If I reload my converted GeoJSON layer into QGIS it shows some stretching horizontally when compared to the original GML, but it seems to work.

Comment: I guess you will not get lucky with that broken installation. Have a look into the postinstall.log file to see why the CRS are not updated. But that should be another question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. No the installation failed on my host (which is a mac) but its my own fault because I have incompatible prerequisites (Python mismatch regarding matplotlib for example). The reason was I wanted to re-test it on another environment. On my Windows 2012 server it is running (I run 'as administrator'). I tested it with your configuration but the coordinates remain unchanged (many thanks again for your help). I noticed the GUI is not working flawless: sometimes dropdown selections are missed and need to be reselect. Maybe it is a Windows 2012 64 bit thing.

Comment: By the way I am testing using the public gml file 'gemeentegrenzen.gml' of the Netherlands. Download link: https://www.pdok.nl/nl/producten/pdok-downloads/basis-registratie-kadaster/bestuurlijke-grenzen-actueel (click on 'Download Bestuurlijke Grenzen'). If you like to test it yourself.

Comment: Working with 32-bit QGIS on 64-bit Windows 7 gives me the following extent for Geojson: `xMin,yMin 3.30794;50.7504 : xMax,yMax 7.2275;53.5764` which should be correct for NL. Personally I don`t trust the 64-bit QGIS version yet.

Comment: Well then that must be the cause. The reason I use the 64 bit was because the 32 bit won't run on my system. Well if I have some spare time I will try to install it on my mac host.

Comment: I don't know much about VMware, that might be a reason. You could also try VirtualBox with a Windows or Ubuntu guest system.

Answer (score 1):

Use EPSG:4326 to export the data if you want lat/lng.
Not everything called "something WGS84 something" is in lat/lng.

Comment: The strange thing is I can not find this CRS. If I filter on EPSG or 4326 it only shows 2065, 4818, 4156, 5221, 5513, 5514 CRS'ses. I tried installing it on my Host Mac OsX to (quickly) check if it is an installation issue but failed due to wrong Python dependencies. Thanks for your suggestion by the way.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your CRS picker dialog?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot to my original posting which is better viewable when downloaded.

Comment: Due to my failed installation of QGIS on my Mac I found the excellent utility called 'ogr2ogr'(part of GDAL which is a prerequisite on a Mac installation). See https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/gdal for initialising this utility.
The following command nicely converted my gml file into a Geo JSON format with lat/lng coordinates: 
'ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "GeoJSON" {YOUR OUTPUT FILENAME}.json {YOUR INPUT FILENAME}.gml'.